# Recording Audio from Radio Stream

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-recording

I'm sitting here listening to a radio show that is being broadcast live over an internet stream, but I would like to keep bits and pieces for later-enjoyment. Is there  a way I can easily record streams in real-time? I should note also (not sure if it's necessary or not) that this stream requires me to first login before listening.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc).

> #### The cross-platform open-source multimedia framework, player and server
>
> VLC media player is a highly portable multimedia player and multimedia framework [capable of reading most audio and video formats](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php) (MPEG-2, MPEG-4, H.264, DivX, MPEG-1, mp3, ogg, aac ...) as well as DVDs, Audio CDs VCDs, and various streaming protocols. See the full features list.
>
> **It can also be used as a media converter** or a server to stream in unicast or multicast in IPv4 or IPv6 on networks.

I've used for exactly what you are asking and it works great.

To do this you have to:

- Media (Medio)
- Convert / Save... (Convertir / Salvar...)
- Network tab, input the origin stream (Tab Red, escribir la dirección de origen)
- Press <kbd>Convert / Save</kbd> (Presionar Convertir / Salvar)
- Output: Check File. Select a filename and path. (Salidas: Tildar Archivo. Elegir nombre de archivo y directorio)
- Make sure Audio Codec is selected. (En códec de audio, tildar Audio)
- Hit <kbd>Save</kbd> (Salvar)

Comment: Do you have a short bulleted list demonstrating how to get a stream onto my computer as a file?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: the only problem is that I've got it installed in spanish and I could just end up confusing you. Let me see if its in english on my netbook.

Comment: @Voyager: You can give the instructions in spanish. I read it fairly well.

Comment: @Jonathan: There really isn't any more to it. Some options may have different names, but its really easy to "press thingys until it works" :)

Comment: Furthermore, I didn't know you could read spanish. Good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **[Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/)**

[image]

Features:

> Why to use Screamer Radio
>
> It's easy to use
>
> It's not bloated
>
> It's ad free
>
> It has no spyware
>
> It has a huge database of radio
>   stations
>
> It has a cool peak meter ;)
>
> You can easily record what you're
>   listening to
>
> You can hide it in the system tray
>
> You can play back on multiple
>   soundcards
>
> .. and it's free!

Supported Stream Types

> Shoutcast and Icecast MP3 Streaming
>
> Icecast OGG Vorbis Streaming
>
> **WMA Streaming**
>
> AAC Streaming

Recording Features

> Recording buffer: start recording in
>   the middle and still save the entire
>   song!
>
> Direct MP3 Audio stream saving, no
>   loss of quality!
>
> Direct OGG Vorbis stream saving, no
>   loss of quality!
>
> Or encode OGG Vorbis as MP3 using Lame
>
> Encode WMA or AAC to MP3 using Lame

Open URL or select your favorite station from the presets, then hit Rec, it doesn't get much easier

A portable version Screamer Radio is available.

Comment: SR is a great program, but unfortunately capturing WMA with it will require re-encoding and thus quality loss

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question from @Jonathan Sampson about how to save a stream onto your computer as a file...
A mostly(*) free native solution from [Matt Beckler](http://www.mbeckler.org/scripts.php) that uses mplayer and lame:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Save streaming audio to an mp3 file. Requires lame.
# This script will record for the duration entered below.
# Customize the stream URL, duration, filename, and working directory.
# 
# Written by Matthew Beckler (matthew at mbeckler dot org)

STREAM="http://1.2.3.4:8140"
DURATION="1:30:00"
DATESTR="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
# Don't include .wav or .mp3 at the end of the variable below:
FILENAME="Stream_dump_$DATESTR"
WORKINGDIR="/data/pub/audio/podcasts/"

cd $WORKINGDIR
rm -rf $FILENAME.{wav,mp3}
mplayer $STREAM -endpos $DURATION -vo null \
    -ao pcm:waveheader:file=$FILENAME.wav &> /dev/null
lame $FILENAME.wav $FILENAME.mp3 &> /dev/null
rm -rf $FILENAME.wav
```

(*) script requires lame, but I'm guessing you're ok with libraries whose licensing might be non-free

Answer (score 0):

You can check out a program I have developed to this end (front end for stream recording). It relies on MPlayer, VLC, or any other recorder you choose. It sports quite a few interesting features (IMHO), give it a try...

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamrecnet/files/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NO23 recorder, it uses the stereo-mix for system-wide sound recording.

[Link](http://www.no23.de/no23web/)

Unfortunately the site is only available in German, but it should be easy to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Many tools can do that in Windows. (For Linux look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/666751/47206).) Some lists [here](http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-internet-radio-recorder/) and [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/435-10-internet-radio-recording.html).

I also recommend **Screamer Radio**, already mentioned.

Also:

[streamWriter](https://streamwriter.org/en/)

[RadioSure](http://www.radiosure.com/)

[TapinRadio](http://www.raimersoft.com/tapinradio.aspx)

[RarmaRadio](http://www.raimersoft.com/rarmaradio.aspx)

All mentioned can save radio songs with tags for title, artist etc. **StreamWriter** deserves a special position as it is able to record multiple streams simultaneously, schedule recording of specific stations, titles, artists, etc.