# Record streaming audio

Tags: windows-xp, recording, streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recording Audio from WMP Stream](https://superuser.com/questions/41896/recording-audio-from-wmp-stream)

I'm sure the quality will be pretty low, but there's some music I just have to have.

How do I record streaming audio on Windows XP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Stereo Mix option, you can use that along with Audacity (a free audio editor) to record anything that is coming through your speakers. There are also some pay solutions.

Many of the modern manufacturers of audio cards have removed that option specifically because you are able to record streaming music.

Its actually really good quality.

Answer (score 1):

Record the "Stereo Mix" channel (you may have to make it a visible recording option).

Another option if you can't get "stereo mix" available to you:

Get a male-to-male stereo cable, and a stereo splitter dongle (one male to double female).

Splitter into Stereo line-out on soundcard, speakers and one end of cable into splitter, other end of cable into line-in on the card.

Then record "line-in".

Not elegant, but gets around most audio DRM, which is often why 'stereo mix' is not available to you these days.

Also, the quality should be fine if you're not expecting digital perfection. :)

There are also [guides out there](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-us&q=xp+stereo+mix+out+option&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) for XP and Vista (and probably other operating systems) to turn Stereo mix option back on.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like, with a microphone ?

(this is as simple as they come) :: Plug the mic in, open sound recorder in windows (talking XP here, there should be something in 7 and Vista as well) - it's in Accessories/Entertainment, and click Record.