# How to record online radio?

Tags: mp3, audio-recording, audio-streaming, internet-radio, pls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recording Audio from WMP Stream](https://superuser.com/questions/41896/recording-audio-from-wmp-stream)

I have this `pls` files that allows my media player to play this online radio. I would like to record an interval of the stream and save it to MP3. I could use [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) and [Sound Recorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_Recorder_%28Windows%29) together to achieve this, but I'm sure there is a better way.

For example, Windows Sound Recorder saves to WMA, and I want MP3. And using Virtual Audio Cable seems like overengineering this solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VLC (although not the perfect tool for the job) does this quite easily for you. Using the 'advanced open' dialogue, you can select your stream, and save it to a specific location (in mp3 if you wish).

Further editing can be done using Audacity.

Comment: VLC saves to 128 kbps MP3 by default. But I could change it.

Answer (score 1):

I use "Replay Media Catcher" from Applian for this kind of thing. Very good and can save directly to MP3.

Answer (score 1):

[AIMP](http://aimp.ru/) has that feature build in.